# How to fix the size of a ggplot in R while saving it with png()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Map size with lat/long 38.31536111,-76.55011111
is different from map 
with lat/long 59.5624775,-139.7410994  (plotting points on the map)

while saving it with png()

How to keep the same size?  height and width isn't enough?

EDIT: full code

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE)
lat = data$lat
long = data$long
world<-map_data('usa')
sf<-data.frame(long=long,lat=lat)
p <- ggplot(height=600, width=800) +
geom_polygon( data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) 
p <- p + geom_point(data=sf,aes(long,lat),colour="white",size=1)
p
```

data file:

```
"lat","long"
59.5624775,-139.7410994
42.38748056,-94.61803333
```

If I remove the first line in the data file, the map size is different (bigger), than when both lines are present

Comment: We would sure love a reproducible example.

Comment: height and width should be specified in `png()` to control image size, not in `ggplot()`.

Comment: ...and you might have better results in general using `ggsave()` rather than `png()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is a bit of a mess mate, so I fixed it into reproducable format below. Solution is already given by @joran - you need to specify size in `png()`.

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
#specify size here
png("world.png",height=600,width=800)

#here is a way to create very simple data frame from you coordinates
data <- read.table(textConnection("
lat long 
59.5624775 -139.7410994 
42.38748056 -94.61803333"),header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)
long=data$long
lat=data$lat
world <- map_data('usa')
sf<-data.frame(long=long,lat=lat)
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) + 
geom_point(data=sf,aes(long,lat),colour="white",size=1)

#this saves png in your current directory
dev.off()
```

EDIT: Ups, now I made some error in the previous code, now it's fixed.

[image]

Comment: I generated two images, one with the first lat/long, and other with both lat/long, as per you code.  The image sizes are still different. EDIT: I mean, the map sizes, the sizes of images are the same.

Comment: sorry about the messy code.  Just learning R, and I should've cleaned it up before posting.

Comment: Never mind.  I changed the lat/long in the sf<-data.frame line, and that fixed it.  Thank you for your help :)